# Java, how to read multiple data types from one function input?

Tags: java, function, types

let's say I want to call a function in my code and I want to input an integer in one case and in another case a string/boolean/char... I know `var` is used for doing this but it doesn't work in my code.

what do I need to change/add for it work and be able to receive different data types?

```
public static void add(var num){//-here is var but I get an error
           //do something
        }
```

Comment: _I know `var` is used for doing this_ -- No. Use `add(Object)` with subsequent `instanceof` checks and casts to types you're going to handle, or overload the method with all supported types (e.g., `add(int)`, `add(String)`, ...) (depends on your case and the actual dispatch).

Comment: You ca use the same logic of the `main()` function, `String[] args` an array of parameters

Comment: @Hamza Abdaoui but im using functions so main doesn't help me here

Comment: I was talking about using an array of parameters, like in `main`! But I think what you're realy looking for is the "generic types", check this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know var is used for doing this but it doesn't work in my code.

No, it is not.

Java is strongly and simply typed. Things have a type. There is no dynamic/ducktyping type. `var` is not that. var is just syntax sugar.

In a ducktyping/dynamic language, you could write:

```
var x;
x = 5;
x = "Hello";
```

In java, **you cannot do that**. `var x;` is a compiler error.

`var x` in java is just shorthand for: Take the type of the thing you are assigning to x on this very line. Assume I meant that write that type out. In other words, `var` is allowed only if you inline initialize:

```
var x = "Hello"; // legal; and 100% the same as writing String x = "Hello"
x = 5; // compiler error. x is of type String, and 5 isn't a string.
```

> what do I need to change/add for it work and be able to receive different data types?

What is the common type amongst String, boolean, char, and int?

`Object` is the best available answer, and it's not a great one. So that's what you'd have to do:

```
public static void add(Object num) {
    if (num instanceof Number) { .... }
    else if (num instanceof String) { .... }
    else if (num instanceof Boolean) { .... }
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only numbers, strings, and booleans allowed");
}
```

But this is extremely non-java. It sounds like you want to design a weakly typed system, where `"5"` and `5` are treated the same, and `true` and `1` are treated the same. I suggest you don't do that.

An alternative is to just make that many methods. In java, a method is defined by its entire signature: The name, but also the param types and return types, as well as the type the method is in. So, you can make more than one add method:

```
public static void add(String num) { ... }
public static void add(int num) { ... }
```